# C++ system calls "SED"

Tags: c++, system-calls

I am trying to run the sep command using a c++ program. When I compile the below code I get a warning for `argv[0]="sep";` stating `"deprecated conversion from string constant to âchar*â [-Wwrite-strings]."` when I run the below program I get Exec Failed! ever time from the line below execvp().

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t pid;
    int fail;

    argv[0] = "sep";

    int i=0;
    while(i < argc){
        cout<< i << ": " << argv[i] <<endl;
        i++;
    }

    if(argc < 5){
        cout<< "./upload -i -r <key> <source> <destination>" <<endl;
    }else{
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            cout<<"Fork Failed!\n";
            exit(1);
        }else if(pid == 0){                 //if you are in the child process
            fail = execvp("scp", argv); //execute command, return -1 on fail
            cout<< "Exec Failed!\n";
            exit(1);
        }else{
            int status;
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);   //wait for each pid
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `execvp` fails, you should check [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) what's wrong. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string.

Comment: nice, "No such file or directory."

./upload -r -i NewKey.pem UploadFolder ubuntu@ec2-54-245-152-141.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:uploaded

is what i am running in the command line where NewKey.pem is the file for my AWS server, and the other two are source and destination. sep -r -i key source destination works when not inside the program...

Comment: Even though you figured it out, the line `argv[0] = "scp";` is still suspect; if your program name is less than three letters, this will probably seg fault.  Just an FYI...

Comment: good call. i am going to build a new array calls args and set each value = to the argv except set args[0] = "scp"

Comment: Also this way, the user does not have to specify the flags. i can force them to flag what i want.

Comment: Good call!  Sorry I wasn't of more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow...typo.

Where argv[0] = "sep";

should have been "scp"

```
    char** args;

    args = new char*[argc+2]; //forcing 2 flags
    args[0] = "scp";
    args[1] = "-i";
    args[2] = "-r";
    args[3] = argv[1]; //key
    args[4] = argv[2]; //source
    args[5] = argv[3]; //destination

    execvp(args[0], args);
```

Comment: lol... I never would've figured that out.  I'll remove my answer, as it is detracting from the real issue.

Comment: real issue = my fat fingers :P